# Standard deviation of average events per ID in R

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics

**Background**

I've got this dataset `d`:

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b"),
                event = c("G12","R2","O99","B4","B4","A24","L5","J15"),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

It's got 2 people (`ID`s) in it, and they each have some events.

**The problem**

I'm trying to get an average number (count) of events per person, along with a standard deviation for that average, all in one result (it can be a dataframe or not, doesn't matter).

In other words I'm looking for something like this:

```
| Mean |  SD  |
|------|------|
| 4.00 | 2.83 |
```

**What I've tried**

I'm not far off, I don't think -- it's just that I've got 2 separate pieces of code doing these calculations. Here's the mean:

```
d %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(event = length(event)) %>%
  summarise(ratio = mean(event))

# A tibble: 1 x 1
  ratio
  <dbl>
1     4
```

And here's the SD:

```
d %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(event = length(event)) %>%  
  summarise(sd = sd(event))

# A tibble: 1 x 1
     sd
  <dbl>
1  2.83
```

But I when I try to pipe them together like so...

```
d %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(event = length(event)) %>%
  summarise(ratio = mean(event)) %>%
  summarise(sd = sd(event))
```

... I get an error:

```
Error in `h()`:
! Problem with `summarise()` column `sd`.
i `sd = sd(event)`.
x object 'event' not found
```

Any insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the last two calls to `summarise()` in the same call. The only remaining columns after `summarise()` will be those you named and the grouping columns, so after your second summarise, the `event` column no longer exists.

```r
library(dplyr)

d <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b"),
                event = c("G12","R2","O99","B4","B4","A24","L5","J15"),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

d %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  # the next summarise will be within ID
  summarise(event = length(event)) %>% 
  # this summarise is overall
  summarise(sd = sd(event),
            ratio = mean(event))

#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>      sd ratio
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2.83     4
```

The code is a bit confusing because you are renaming the event variable, and doing the first `summarise()` within groups and the second without grouping. This code would be a little easier to read and get the same result:

```r
d %>%
  count(ID) %>% 
  summarise(sd = sd(n),
            ratio = mean(n))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Gah it's so obvious. I didn't even consider just combining the calls into one `summarise()`. Much obliged!